# Why is Ag+ not hydrolysed?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, hydrolysis

Usually, strong acid anions and strong base cations don't get hydrolysed. But I've noticed through some questions that $\ce{Ag^+}$ doesn't seem to get hydrolysed, why is that? Is there any concept that I'm not aware of that predicts which ions get hydrolysed and which don't, or is it just the ions from strong acids/bases don't get hydrolysed?

Comment: Does Ag2O precipitate when AgNO3 solution neutralised by NaOH ?

Comment: Why would it get hydrolyzed? Big cation, low charge.